# Compare two string arrays with concat strings VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In program is 2 structures with string fields. 
First Structure:

```
   Private Structure A
       Dim str1 as String 
       Dim str2 as String
```

Second Structure:

```
   Private Structure B
       Dim str1 as String
```

somewhere in code i assign it to array of

```
Dim a() as A
Dim b() as B
```

for Example in A we have name and surname in two string 
in B name and surname in one
in result i need to compare composition of str1 and str2 of a() with str1 b().
in cpp this would be like

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < sizeB;i++)
   {
      if(!(strcmp(strcat(a[i].str1,a[i].str2),b[j].str1)) printf("GOOD!");
   }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: And it wouldn't actually be that would it.. because `strcmp` has a return value that is actually useful.  calling `strcmp` without checking its return value is rather pointless.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: how to compare string in VB.net may be? I  don't understand logic of VB at all)
 i wrote a question 
in result i need to compare composition of str1 and str2 of a() with str1 b().

Comment: But how compare? you are comparing one A in A with all B in b, so do you want to find equals, or...

Comment: is it really  important?) 
in program it's can do 1 operation if equals and if not -> second? or i wrong?)
ok. ALL A to ALL B. -_- in cpp code it's showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your cpp code translated to VB, with some minor optimizations:

```
For i = 0 To (a.Length - 1)
    Dim strA = String.Join(" ", a(i).str1, a(i).str2)

    For j = 0 To (b.Length - 1)
        Dim strB = b(j).str1

        If String.Equals(strA, strB, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
            Console.WriteLine("GOOD")
        End If

    Next
Next
```

Comment: how to add a space beetween concat? 
`String.Concat(a(i).str1 ,String.Concat(" ", a(i).str2)`

Comment: Alternatively: `Dim strA = a(i).str1 & " " & a(i).str2`

Comment: better))) because in real i must concat 3 string and it was awful(but with spaces xD)

Comment: You can also use `String.Join()` if you need a space between every piece. See my updated answer.

Comment: found one mistake) if finded 
`exit for` to economy time)))

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase that?

Comment: `If String.Equals(strA, strB, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then Console.WriteLine("GOOD")
exit For 
End If`
if we found a requried string we can move to next and find  another)))

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with cpp, however, you can use LINQ:

```
Dim comparisons = From a1 In a
                  From b1 In b
                  Let a1Concat = a1.str1 & a1.str2
                  Let comp = String.Compare(a1Concat, b1.str1)
' you can enumerate the query with a For-Each ' 
For Each result In comparisons
    Dim a1Str1 As String = result.a1.str1
    Dim a1Str2 As String = result.a1.str2
    Dim a1Concat As String = result.a1Concat
    Dim b1Str1 As String = result.b1.str1
    Dim comparison As Int32 = result.comp
Next
```

Comment: o_O my mind is blown. o_O i'm trying to understand it)))

Comment: You can use `Where comp = 0` if you only want to take the _"GOOD"_.

Comment: According to the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx), you shouldn't use `Compare` to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (A.str1 + A.str2) = B.str1 Then Debug.Print("GOOD")
```